# Is it possible to pivot a table in excel and report all the values

Tags: excel

I'm not sure this is possible but I'm trying to do the following in excel. I have a table with the names of people and the team they belong to, and I want to make a roster for each team. So I have something like this:

```
Michael Jordan Bulls
Dennis Rodman Bulls
Kobe Bryant Lakers
Steve Nash Lakers
```

And I want to get something like:

```
Bulls Lakes
Michale Kobe
Dennis Steve
```

Is there a strait-forward way to do this?

Comment: depends on what your interpretation of "straightforward" is :) [This superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/345841/excel-text-values-in-a-pivot-table) will provide you with a solution

Answer (score 0):

Create a PivotTable with both Team and Name as Row Labels and Show in Tabular Form. To show the teams side by side, copy and Paste Special Values the PT then select and drag one team to suit.